# Override WCF Client Methods

Tags: c#, wcf, overriding

I have a WCF service that I use in one of my applications.  Everything is working just fine, but I am trying to create some test classes that have the same API, but avoid the trip to the server to get their information.  For example:

```
// Goes to the server to get a list of names.  It might be a while.
MyClient client = new MyClient();
string[] theNames = client.GetSpitefulUsers();
...

// This is what I would use in a test case...
public FakeClient : MyClient
{
  ...
  public override string[] GetSpitefulUsers()
  {
    // This returns almost immediately, but I can't just override it because the
    // 'MyClient' definition is generated code.
    return new string[] {"Aldo", "Barry", "Cassie"};
  }
}
```

So what is the easiest way to provide this type of functionality without having to resort to clever hacks, mocking libraries, etc?

Comment: Look up dependency injection / inversion of control

Comment: Why would you want to avoid mocking libraries? This is exactly what they're for. It's easier to learn to use a library than to hand-code fake objects for every test case.

Comment: @Dave Thanks for the incredibly vague / off topic comment.

Comment: @Joel Because I am interested in the technical aspect of what this question is dealing with.  I included the part about mocking, workarounds, design change, etc. to prevent off topic responses.  The question is "how can I override....?" not "how would you redesign this code....?"

Comment: @A.R. I'm having a bit of a busy day at work so didn't have time to write a full answer. Try googling 'dependency injection unit testing' - the first link (albeit in java) illustrates the techniques you're looking for (incidentally, your accepted answer demonstrates DI :) )

Comment: @Dave: If I didn't know what it was, I wouldn't have asked the audience to omit it from their responses.

Comment: @A.R. I guess it's a difference of opinion then - I say that DI is a design pattern (Martin Fowler and others agree) rather than a clever hack, and while there are DI/IOC container libraries out there, they're not prerequisite for implementation. The fact that your accepted answer is a very clear example of the manual 'setter' variant of dependency injection means you might benefit from reading around this subject in more detail. HTH

Comment: @Dave - You are missing the point, I am not interested in discussing design patterns, blah blah blah.  I wanted to know if there was "a way to override.. generated methods".  The answer I accepted was an example of the "easiest way to provide... functionality"  The discussion design/techniques is not useful information in this case.

Comment: @A.R. And using a design pattern provided the solution you wanted - QED

Comment: @Dave: True, but a vague mention of them did not answer the question.  In the meantime we can all agree that programming solves programming problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF service reference has an interface, so all your logic should refer to that interface, not service client. In such case, you will be able to choose, what implementation(real or fake) to pass to your application logic.

Let's say your WCF service interface is this:

```
public interface IWcfInterface {
     string[] GetTheNames();
}
```

And your application logic class looks like:

```
public class ApplicationLogic {

     public IWcfInterface WcfInterface {get;set;}

     public SomeLogic() {
         WcfInterface.GetTheNames();
     } 
}
```

So in case you need real implementation, you just pass it to WcfInterface property of your application logic (usually this does dependency injection container).

Fake implementation will also look simple:

```
public FakeImplementation : IWcfInterface {
     public string[] GetTheNames() {
         return new string[] { "foo", "bar" };
     }
}
```

Comment: I guess it doesn't really deal with overriding, but this is by far the easiest solution that has been suggested.  I forgot all about the interface part for some reason....

Answer (score 0):

if i am right the compiler will suggest to use the keyword new instead.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx

This msdnpage will explain how to use it.

```
public class BaseC
{
    public int x;
    public void Invoke() { }
}
public class DerivedC : BaseC
{
    new public void Invoke() { }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, 'new' technically works but won't function in the same way as a proper override.